# Assign variable on a remote server

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to assign a variable using SSH. I want to simply echo the content of the variable. Here is my little script :

```
#!/bin/bash
IP_PUBLIC="192.168.0.1"
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$IP_PUBLIC" '
    COMMUNITY=$(uname -n);
    echo '"$COMMUNITY"';
'
```

Everytime I run it it echo an empty line. I expect to echo the hostname of the machine

Comment: Try adding `-t` to your SSH command.

Comment: I get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to drop the inner single quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
IP_PUBLIC="192.168.0.1"
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$IP_PUBLIC" '
    COMMUNITY=$(uname -n);
    echo "$COMMUNITY";
'
```

The outer single quotes already protect everything inside them from the local shell; the remote shell receives

```
COMMUNITY=$(uname -n);
echo "$COMMUNITY"
```

to execute, which is correctly quoted.